# Firebase messaging in production

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a project that works with FCM. On the localhost, every thing works fine and I get the token for FCM; but, in production, I get this error:

> FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://myxdomain.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('https://myxdomain/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (403) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

I'm deploying my app in an Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/229#issuecomment-395382187), you need to add `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file in **correct** folder. It may be something like this: `/var/www/...`